# Highlighting a textfield value

Tags: ruby

Hi guys i am using a dropdownlist which have the value please specify other, when that value is selected in prompts out a textfield which has the value please specify other, but for the user to type in anything in the textfield he has to delete the value manually..i am looking for a code which can delete the value automatically when the user type in the textfield..

Comment: It helps if you specify what framework you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can make textbox hints.  Even better, reuse someone else's code:

http://remysharp.com/2007/01/25/jquery-tutorial-text-box-hints/

Example: http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/input_hint.html